# How to remove ul li formatting from list of attributes in Ubercart order email template?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I would like to update my customer order email and printable invoice so that each product line item looks like this:

> 1 x SHIRTRED | Red | Tshirt

- 1 is the quantity ordered
- SHIRTRED is the SKU
- Red is the attribute option that was chosen
- Tshirt is the product name

I have already updated my uc-order--customer.tpl.php code to look like this:

```
<b><?php print $product->qty; ?> x </b> <?php print $product->model; ?> | <?php print $product->title; ?> | <?php print $product->details; ?>
```

The attribute options are printed as a ul list, which causes them to wrap to the next line below the other info for this product. I would like to remove the ul li formatting from the product's attributes in the customer order email and the printable invoice so that the info can be on a single line/table row. I found this in uc_order.module:

```
$product->details .= theme('item_list', array('items' => $attributes));
```

Would I just change 'item_list' to something else in a template.php function? If so, what would I change it to? If not, how else can I accomplish this change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I was asking for, but I did find a workaround that works for the most part. I copied the uc-order--customer.tpl.php  file into my theme dir and added css for the ul to the head in that file. (display: inline-block and a few padding, margin, and list-style styles). The only issue now is the emailed order invoice. The CSS doesn't follow along into the email, so it's a bit of a mess. Open to any suggestions on how to handle that, or a better way overall.

EDITED TO ADD: I ended up copying the product line items from the uc-order--admin.tpl.php file. The attributes therein are not styled as a list, so it was a breeze to use that code.